# create a dynamic form in a Jtabbedpane via a Jbutton

Tags: java, mysql, swing, dynamic

i have two Jtabbedpane, one were there is my Jtable and my Jbutton ( add, update, remove ), what i want is, when i click on " Add ", a dynamic form is generated. Let's say i have in my table from my DB 4 colomns, when i click on " Add ", 4 label and 4 Jtextfield must be generated. i tried to create a Jlabel in my Tabbedpane for a test, but that didn't work

```
    private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    jTabbedPane1.setSelectedComponent(jPanel2);
    JLabel label1 = new JLabel("Test");
    jPanel2.add(label1);}
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example).

Comment: The GUI editor may be hindering your effort to learn Swing.

Comment: N.B. rather than add a label dynamically, it is typically better to add it at start up, then set the text dynamically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your panel (or any container, actually) has been displayed by the time you add another component to it, then you need to [revalidate](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#revalidate%28%29) and [repaint](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#repaint%28%29) your panel, because the components' hierarchy is invalidated on [add](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#add%28java.awt.Component%29) method call.

On the other hand, in this particular case I'd use a modal dialog to show the new item's form. See [How to Make Dialogs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html) tutorial.

---

### Edit

Based on this comment:

> *My request is just how i can generate dynamicaly a number x of form fields by getting x number of columns from my DB.*

There are several ways to achieve this, but you can make a reusable class to help you. The main question you should have present is how many fields you'll need and what are the labels for those fields. Once you have figured out the answer to that question then you could use something like this:

```
public class FormGenerator {

    private Map<String, String> data;
    private JPanel panel;

    public FormGenerator(List<String> formLabels) {
        super();
        initMap(formLabels);
        initPanel(formLabels);
    }

    private void initMap(List<String> formLabels) {
        data = new HashMap();
        for (String label : formLabels) {
            data.put(label, "");
        }
    }

    private void initPanel(List<String> formLabels) {
        int numberOfFields = formLabels.size();
        panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(numberOfFields, 2, 6, 6));

        for (String fieldLabel : formLabels) {
            JLabel label = new JLabel(fieldLabel);
            label.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.TRAILING);
            panel.add(label);

            JTextField textField = new JTextField(15);
            textField.putClientProperty("Textfield.For.Field", fieldLabel);
            panel.add(textField);
        }
    }

    public Map<String, String> getDataFromTextFields() {
        for (Component comp : panel.getComponents()) {
            if (comp instanceof JTextField) {
                JTextField textField = (JTextField)comp;
                String key = (String)textField.getClientProperty("Textfield.For.Field");
                String value = textField.getText().trim();
                data.put(key, value);
            }
        }
        return data;
    }


    public JPanel getPanel() {
        return panel;
    }
}
```

Note the underlying data structure could be a map or whatever that suit your requirements. This `FormGenerator` class could be easily used in combination with [`JOptionPane`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html) as shown in the following code snippet:

```
// You have to figure out formLabels list
// The same column identifiers in your table maybe?

FormGenerator formGenerator = new FormGenerator(formLabels);                
JPanel formPanel = formGenerator.getPanel();

int option = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null
                                         , formPanel
                                         ,"Add item"
                                         , JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION
                                         , JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);

if (option == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION) {
    Map<String, String> data = formGenerator.getDataFromTextFields();
    for (String key : data.keySet()) {
        System.out.println(String.format("%1s : %2s", key, data.get(key)));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you first of all, but i think you didn't get the problem well . My request is just how i can generate dynamicaly  a number x of form fields by getting x number of columns from my DB

Comment: @dic19 what if i have two JtabbedPane, and i want to use FormGenerator in the second JtabbedPane instead of using a JoptionPane ?

Comment: In this example `FormGenerator#getPanel()` returns a `JPanel` instance which you can add as a new tab into your second `JTabbedPane`. The very best advantage on returning a `JPanel` is that you can add this component wherever you need to. @Jack